# How to put xampp localhost website online?

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I am new to the WordPress. I have a made WordPress website in xampp localhost, now I want to show that site to my friend before making it online without using any hosting services, but can not show him because it is on localhost.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: ok got it, @halfer thank you for letting me understand this. I am new to stackoverflow, so will take care of this onwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution to show is to share your screen on a video call if you do not want to spend money on hosting. Or you can use teamviewer.

**UPDATED ANSWER - MARCH 03 2018**
Now you can use a tool called `ngrok` which provides a secure tunneling. You will get a temporary url for your localhost. More information is at

https://ngrok.com

Comment: Ok perfect, I have done this, it worked. @Krishnadas PC

Answer (score 5):

**You can follow below steps for this, I am assuming your website name is "myweb":**

1) Go to your website folder in **"Xampp/htdocs/myweb"** and compress your website folder to make tar or zip.
2) Buy linux hosting from any hosting service provider. I would prefer **hostgator.com**. Just ensure they give **"CPANEL"** with this hosting.
3) After you purchase this plan, you will get URL and credentials to login to **"cpanel"**. Login to **"cpanel"** by opening link **"www.myweb.com/cpanel"**
4) Click on option **"File Manager"** in FILES tab.
5) On left side panel, click on **"public_html"**.
6) Then click on **"Upload"** on top panel.
7) Click on **"Select File"**. 
8) When upload finish come back in **"public_html"** folder and right click on this compressed file, click **"Extract"**.
9) Ensure that when you are clicking on **"public_html"**, you are able to view folders **"wp-admin", "wp-content"** etc.(and all other content of your website) on right side pane.
10) Now its time to set database. Go to "CPANEL" homepage again as we did in beginning and click on **"MySQL Databases"** in DATABASES section. Create new database, create new user, add user to database(give any password), give privileges to user for this created database.
11) Now go to "CPANEL" homepage again and then to **"File Manager"->"public_html"**. Right click on file **"wp-config.php"** and select **"Edit"**. Click OK. Now change 'DB_NAME', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASSWORD' here. Give same values here as we did in previous step. Do not change 'DB_HOST', let it be "localhost".
12) Now we have website ready, database settings ready, its time to populate database with data we had in localhost.
13) So first we fetch SQL data from your local machine in form of SQL file. In your browser type **localhost/phpmyadmin**. Click on your database on left side. Click on **"Export"** on top panel. Select **"Format"** as **"SQL"**. Click on **"Go"**. Save the file anywhere and open it with any editor. Replace all occurences of **"localhost"** with **"www.myweb.com"**. Save the file.
14) Now its time to import this SQL data into remote server. Go to "CPANEL" homepage. Then click on **"phpMyAdmin"**. Click on database name you have created here before. This time click on **"Import"** and upload **"SQL"** file which we just modified on local computer. Click on **"GO"**. You should see all your tables in this database now.
15) All set, just go to browser and type **"www.myweb.com"**. Your site is up !

Comment: thank you but is there any way to make a link of localhost and send to friend , without using any hosting service becuase once my friend will verify the site then after I will purchase domain and hosting service.

Comment: For that I think solution proposed by @Krishnadas PC is apt. You can use teamviewer for live demo.

Answer (score 3):

You can put your XAMPP server online without buying a hosting plan from web hosting provider, all you have to do is, get these followings.

1. Allow external connections to Apache HTTP server through the firewall on port 80.
2. Get a Static IP from your Internet Service Provider (ISP) (contact your ISP).
3. Share the static public IP which you've got from ISP to your friend.
   *you can access XAMPP locally using http://127.0.0.1/index.html now change the local IP with your public static IP lets say(http://10.123.53.X/index.html)*

Comment: What about security?, Is it secure to use xampp online?

Answer (score 1):

Its really easy, just go to a Free Hosting Provider that has no LIMITATIONS! Has mySQL Server Creation and With Unlimited Disk Space that can be Used (I personally Use it), it is ProFreeHost.com... Go Check it Out, and get a Domain (for example: mywebsite.ml or .tk) from Freenom.com, you can learn how to setup by watching a Video on YouTube!

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up in a free sub domain to upload your website.

[Free Subdomain](http://freesubdomain.org/)

Then install filezilla to transfer your files to you subdomain.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to purchase any kind of Domain or something just change your base_url in framework which you are using like i am using codeigniter it will be

> like http://localhost/home

> to http://192.168.1.2/home

just call locally this address.

its done

you can view your site on each system.

Enjoy!